# How to set a floating div at the bottom left of my content?

Tags: jquery, css

i'd like to be able to position a div at the bottom left of my content (just like div n°2 on this wireframe).

The trick is i'd like to do it WITHOUT having to insert it manually inside the "content" div.

(context : I have more than 500 wordpress posts where i'd like to do that, and the manual insert solution seems painful and approximative at best).

I tried using position:absolute;bottom:0px; but if I do that, div 2 is on top of my content and masks some of my text content.

Any clue about how I could align div2's bottom to the exact bottom of my content ? With Jquery maybe ?

Here's an overview of my HTML code.

```
<div class="contenu">
    <div id="1"><img class="ad_300x250" style="float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;" src="300x250_3.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="2"><img class="ad_300x250" src="300x250_3.jpg" /></div>
    <p>Loin, très loin, au delà des monts Mots, à mille lieues des pays Voyellie et Consonnia, demeurent les Bolos Bolos. Ils vivent en retrait, à Bourg-en-Lettres, sur les côtes de la Sémantique, un vaste océan de langues.</p>
            <p>Un petit ruisseau, du nom de Larousse, coule en leur lieu et les approvisionne en règlalades nécessaires en tout genre; un pays paradisiagmatique, dans lequel des pans entiers de phrases prémâchées vous volent litéralement tout cuit dans la bouche. Pas même la toute puissante Ponctuation ne régit les Bolos Bolos - une vie on ne peut moins orthodoxographique.</p>
            <h2>Titre 2 </h2>
            <p>Un jour pourtant, une petite ligne de Bolo Bolo du nom de Lorem Ipsum décida de s'aventurer dans la vaste Grammaire.</p>
            <h3>Titre 3 </h3>
            <p>Le grand Oxymore voulut l'en dissuader, le prevenant que là-bas cela fourmillait de vils Virgulos, de sauvages </p>
            <h2>Titre 2 </h2>
            <p>Pointdexclamators et de sournois Semicolons qui l'attendraient pour sûr au prochain paragraphe, mais ces mots ne firent écho dans </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    l'oreille du petit Bolo
                </li>
                <li>
                    qui ne se laissa point déconcerter.
                </li>
                <li>
                    Il pacqua ses 12 lettrines, glissa son initiale dans sa panse et se mit en route.
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p>Alors qu'il avait gravi les premiers flancs de la chaîne des monts Italiques, il jeta un dernier regard sur la skyline de Bourg-en-Lettres, sa ville alphanatale, la headline d'Alphabetville, la subline de sa propre rue, le passage Motus. Le coeur lourd et nostalgique, une question rhétorique lui coula le long de la joue, puis, il se remit en route. </p>
            <p>En chemin, il rencontra un Copy. Le Copy prévint le petit Bolo que là d'où il venait, il avait déjà maintes et maintes fois été ressaisi, et que tout ce qui désormais restait de leurs origines était le mot "et", et que le petit Bolo ferait bien de se raviser, rebrousser chemin et retourner en son sain et sauf bercail. Mais toutes bonnes</p>

            <p>Alors qu'il avait gravi les premiers flancs de la cha&icirc;ne des monts Italiques, il jeta un dernier regard sur la skyline de Bourg-en-Lettres, sa ville alphanatale, la headline d'Alphabetville, la subline de sa propre rue, le passage Motus. Le coeur lourd et nostalgique, une question rh&eacute;torique lui coula le long de la joue, puis, il se remit en route.</p>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give some HTML for context?

Comment: CSS only solution, or JavaScript as well?

Comment: I'm open to Javascript if it's what it takes. I tried using Jquery to compute the exact height where to set the div, but didn't manage to do anything "clean" and effective. I'm a JS / Jquery beginner though, I might have missed something obvious.

Comment: how about selecting last child paragraph, giving it left padding or margin, then absolute position the second image??

Comment: That's rather smart (must admit I didn't think of that), but it wont do the trick, since I can't predict heights : it might be necessary to add padding to *more* than just the last <p>, depending on how high are div 2 and last <p>.

Comment: Actually, (using absolute positionning), any trick that would let me the content be PUSHED aside by the div (rather than being overlayed) would do. Maybe some kind of display:block or something like that ? Ring a bell ? But since absolute positionning takes my div out of the flow, I guess it's impossible.

Comment: ^ your last comment is correct, as far as I am aware.  Setting absolute position takes it out of the flow of the document and thus impossible to get it to behave like a normal div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixing with a CSS rule**

Targeting your comment :

> `context : I have more than 500 wordpress posts where i'd like to do
>   that, and the manual insert solution seems painful and approximative
>   at best

You may combine a pseudo  element and a nth-child selector (please check full browser support)

Only fixture to fix is that a very large ending paragraph will set aside your float one or more lines from bottom. Not a big issue I suppose.

Anyway, using this pseudo you will be able to locate your second div with the css forgetting about the markup.
You could use the **img** tag or the background for image purposes
I stated :before so the image will be wraped by the text of the last paragraph.
in my example I used a color background and a fixed size in order to see the pseudo element

```
.contenu p:nth-last-child(1):before {
    content:" ";   /* Or the image */
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ff0000;  /* or the image */
    float:left;

}
```

See a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FMzKx/)
Of course div id ="2" is not longer required.

**By the Way and Important:**
Not all parsers will be happy with an id starting with a number!!

Comment: !!! You absolutely rock.
It's not bottom-align like I would have liked it to be, but that's a very acceptable compromise - and an elegant solution. Thanks a million.

Only remaining question now is "How do I inject text content in the block". Not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Hello @Baptiste. Quite simple just includ it in the content property as follows   content:" what ever text you want". For more info take a look at w3c or shorter and simple in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Thank you but... I'm sorry, it seams out of my league. What a <ul><li><a> list would look like, for example ?

Comment: @Baptiste, the content property wont enable you to introduce new elements in the DOM tree (HTML tags and so..). Only content as specs describes in w3c http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content. You may include images and other kind of stuff. As I told before, a nice list of possible values for content property is available at  w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Yep, so I found a solution, using the same approach as you suggested, but with jquery instead of CSS (I basically append an existing div before the nth-last p inside .contenu) 
`$('#related').insertBefore($("#article .contenu p:nth-last-of-type(2)"));`
Works like a charm, so, again, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use float: left exactly how you would for div1, but place div2 just before your last paragraph of text.

So...

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left1">
   <!-- DIV 1 -->
   </div>

   <p>Paragraph 1</p>

   <!-- more in the middle -->

   <p>Paragraph 5</p>

   <div class="left2">
   <!-- DIV 2 -->
   </div>

   <p>Paragraph 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work if the last paragraph of text is longer than the image is tall.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but that's rather a quick & dirty way to do that (the div would sometimes be higher than the last line of text, if the last paragraph's height < div's height).

(i'm managing my content with Wordpress, and I'd like not to have to manually insert my div's code in each of my posts, I got more than 1000 of them)

Any way to do that WITHOUT having to play with HTML markup ? CSS, Jquery or combination of both ?

Comment: In that particular case I would suggest javascript which is beyond my expertise.  Hopefully someone else will post an answer.